# Why can't the hidden field find the QuestionID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, hidden-field

The `<h3><%# Eval("questionTitle") %></h3>` is picking up the right value and not returning null, so why isn't the value in the hidden field: `<%# Eval("questionId") %>`? `questionId` is a property in a class and has the right values being passed through it.

- Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page, gives a pretty good example of how to use the Eval method.

http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2009/11/26/asp-net-mvc-viewdata-eval-method.aspx